# Python Django - matching query does not exist when using pk

Tags: python, django

New to Django and Python here so forgive me if this is something simple...

I'm trying to delete an object of type MyClass, but for some reason I keep getting a matching query does not exist error when I am confident the object does in fact exist.

I've written a delete method that looks like this:

```
  def delete(self, request, format=None, *args, **kwargs):

    identifier = request.DATA.get('identifier', None)
    my_object = MyObjectClass.objects.get(pk=identifier)

    if my_object:
      my_object.delete()
    return Response(status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

When I do that, i get the message MyObjectClass matching query does not exist.

However, when i run python manage.py shell, I can retrieve the object this way:

```
my_object = MyObjectClass.objects.get(pk=1001)
```

That works as expected...so obviously whatever is being stored in that identifier variable is incorrect, though I am having trouble figuring out why. My question: is there some type conversion I must do to get this to work? Or does anyone have another idea of why this might be breaking?

Thanks!

Comment: Clarification: you say you've written a "delete method." You mean a Django function-based view, correct? (As opposed to overriding the model's delete method or something)

Comment: right...the above code executes when I send a DELETE request

Comment: aah wait, this is probably the delete method of a class-based view? Everything got so complicated when Django added CBVs...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value of `identifier` must be coming through wrong. Try using the debugger-- `import pdb` at the top and then put in a breakpoint line (`pdb.set_trace()`) below `identifier = foo`. Then run the development server with `manage.py runserver` and when it hits the breakpoint type `identifier` and I'm pretty sure you'll find it isn't 1001. If so, you need to figure out what is wrong with your http request.

I use request.GET rather than request.DATA, by the way; I don't know if that works.

Comment: its printing out u'9743',  though I am unsure where that U is coming from. Does that look familiar to you by chance?

Comment: u just means it's a unicode string and shouldn't matter. Django does type conversions automatically on query lookups. So, when you do `my_object = MyObjectClass.objects.get(pk=9743)`, does that work?

Comment: Ah I just replaced request.DATA with request.GET and it seems to be working now... ill have to do some research to find out why that is.

Comment: It seems request.DATA is still in development: https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/21442 And for now the standard way to access parameters in a DELETE request is to use GET: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/django-users/inpRdwDJZUo